# MySQL query to pull longitude within certain range

Tags: mysql, geolocation, geocoding

I have a query that used a simple **WHERE logitude != '0'** I though would be sufficient to pull only records that have been successfully geo-coded.

I cannot control the quality or if a address is successfully geocoded as the table is read only.  I can only control my query.

The longitude is normally written out with up to 6 decimal places: -81.729345

Data Type of Latitude and Longitude columns are Decimal, Length is 9, Decimals is 6.

I guess I need to make sure I only select records within a certain range of longitude?

I tried this: **Longitude BETWEEN '-89.69%' AND '-72.07%'** with and without the %

But it returns all records, so I know its wrong as some of the records are geo-coded incorrectly (example: 14.359164).

How do I select only within that range and allow for any number of decimal places?

Here is a snippet of the latitude/longitude columns:

```
26.219295   -81.722585
26.280398   -81.629169
26.134763   -81.795894
26.1255 -81.788166
26.403096   -81.787194
26.1219 -81.793919
26.247832   -81.82119
26.22877    -81.795777
26.25278    -81.78444
26.319679   -81.731197
26.02094    -81.685416
26.364607   -81.817356
25.9351 -81.723069
26.392275   -81.818925
40.903837   14.359164
```

Comment: can you run a `show create table xxxx` and publish a few rows of data too so peeps can visualize ?

Comment: @Drew, updated question with sample columns of lat/long...I assume this will suffice.  The table is large and the records themselves are just standard real estate data, not sure how it would help outside of the two columns in question.  Let me know.

Comment: what does the show create table xxx produce

Comment: A huge table...how is that relevant to my question?

Comment: @Drew wants to know the datatype of your `longitude` column. It matters.

Comment: Type is Decimal, Length is 9, Decimals is 6.

Comment: All good, it's just there Decimals to 6 in the question...I'll update the question now to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`latitude` and `longitude` columns often have the `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` data type. Rarely they have a `DECIMAL(10,4)` data type, and sometime in the face of all reason and logic they have a `VARCHAR(15)` or some such data type.

If yours are `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`, your comparisons are done with arithmetic, not text pattern matching. So you want this sort of `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE Longitude BETWEEN -89.69 AND -72.07
```

This will catch -89.69,  -72.07, and all values in between.

This will also work with `DECIMAL` data types.  If you have varchar Longitude data your best bet is to change it to FLOAT.  Failing that, you want

```
 WHERE  CAST(longitude AS DECIMAL(10,4))  BETWEEN -89.69 AND -72.07
```

But this will have *terrible* performance.

The `%` wildcard only works with character datatypes and only with `LIKE` comparisons.

Comment: Perfect, works excellent, great explanation too...thanks so much @ollie